# How to open console app in Windows 11 without using new terminal feature?

Tags: terminal, windows-11, console

I use this console app (Far manager since early Windows versions - it is best commander  ever, the linux Midnight Commander is a pale rip off compared, it grew from Norton Commander and became 100x more powerful with time).

Recently Windows 11 got new update and now there is something called "Terminal".

Now Far is completely broken.

It is now opens not as console app but as a tab in Terminal, after some changes in Terminal settings its windows has no header, I cant see the bottom edge to move it or resize, the font is broken (there are vertical spaces in graphic characters), the setting cannot be opened because it has no header so I cant fix what I've done.

But at any rate - I want same control for this specific console app (and for my Visual Studio console apps) as it was before. I dont want to have a container with muddled and vague control. It gives me zero advantages and huge headache.

Any suggestions? Can I switch it off ?

Comment: How are you opening Far manager?

Comment: See https://boyet.com/blog/windows-terminal-is-now-default-for-console-apps/

Comment: write it as an answer ill accept

Comment: FWIW far works much better in Windows Terminal than in the old console app - have been using it this way for a year and never looked back

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply go to the Terminal Settings (right mouse click on the window title) and change `Default terminal application` to `Windows Console Host`.

Comment: Yep.figured that out too

Answer (score 8):

Change the shortcut to use console host.

For example:

C:\Windows\System32\conhost.exe C:\path to your app\program.exe

This way W11 launches the program directly. Works create for FAR Manager.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Work good, thanks for saving me.

Answer (score 0):

apparently Terminal is a "Windows Store app". So you can simply uninstall it. I think it could be useful for some use cases but for now its not workable.